# Simperium & mogenerator convenience accessors

Tags: core-data, simperium

I'm using Simperium and mogenerator in my project. I've added SPManagedObject entity to the model and set that as the parent class for other entities. For each entity, mogenerator automatically creates a _<entityname>.h and _<entityname>.m file that has several convenience accessors. I've modified the mogenerator build script so each of these subclasses SPManagedObject instead of NSManagedObject. The entity classes simply import the corresponding _<entityname>.h file.

My problem is I'm getting runtime errors when using any of the convenience accessors. For example, for an entity with attribute of type Integer32 called myInteger, the class file property is NSNumber. Mogenerator creates an accessor named myIntegerValue. The errors I'm getting are that myIntegerValue is an unrecognized selector for SPManagedObject. I can work around this obviously but it seems to be indicative of a bigger problem. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem is most often the result of failing to configure the class name in the Core Data model editor. You may have a class `Foo` and an entity `Foo` but they don't automatically go together (they're not required to have the same name). If you don't do this, you get instances of `NSManagedObject` instead of instances of your subclass. And of course, `NSManagedObject` doesn't have those methods.

Select the entity in the model editor and look in the model inspector on the right. Make sure that the class name is configured.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom. I do have the class set to SPManagedObject as instructed in the simperium doc at https://simperium.com/docs/ios/. Appreciate the help.